# C# Control Name

Tags: c#

I have two questions.
I am usinq Devexpress Winforms

1. What is the name of control of the
   Visual studio toolbox.I wanna add a
   control list like visual studi
   toolbox.What is the name?
2. How can I add the flow chart to my
   c# project?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For Dev Express, I would perhaps try something like the XtraNavBar:

[Windows Side Bar Control](http://www.devexpress.com/Products/NET/Controls/WinForms/NavBar/side_bar.xml)

For a flow chart, I don't think Dev Express has a C# winforms flow chart right now.

[See comments from Dev Express](http://www.devexpress.com/Support/Center/p/Q307264.aspx)

Answer (score 1):

@Deneme, The style of control that you see as the Visual Studio Toolbox is called 'an accordion control'. There is not one in the standard forms toolset, but it is not too difficult to build your own out of buttons & panels, and you can tailor it to your own needs and situation.

As for your second question about adding a flow chart, I am not aware of a single tool that you can drag and drop on to a form and set your users loose, but again, it should not be too difficult for you to create panels & buttons to create your own. Depending your needs you may be able to use some pieces of the Office Developers Toolkit to help you get there.